# Аналог нуль-коалесцирующего оператора в Питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def none_aware(val, default):
    return default if val is None else val
```

В библиотеке есть функция которая возвращает либо список либо None, а хочется написать

```
return [HtmlParser(el) for el in none_aware(content.select('...'), [])]
```

Вместо нескольких строк проверок.

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Функция у вас готова, её использование вы показали, нескольких строк проверок писать не нужно. Этот код не работает или в чём суть вопроса? Или вам не нравится, что нужна функция, и вы хотите какую-то встроенную конструкцию?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Is there a Python equivalent of the C# null-coalescing operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4978738/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
return [HtmlParser(el) for el in (content.select('...') or [])]
```

Нужно только учитывать что у класса может быть переопределён метод `__bool__`, но обычно даже в тех редких случаях, когда его переопределяют, его поведение в логических выражениях остаётся в рамках интуитивно ожидаемого.

Comment: `map(HtmlParser, content.select('...') or [])` если список не нужен

Comment: так как функция возвращает либо список либо None, то `or` оператор всегда работает здесь (вне зависимости от того какие объекты  в возвращаемом списке)

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы фанат однострочного кода, то вот:

```
>>> def f(v,d=1): return d if v is None else v
... 
>>> f(None)
1
```

Средствами `python` можно сделать так:

```
>>> a = lambda x: x if x else None
>>> a(None)
>>> a(1)
1
>>> a([i for i in range(10)])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

А если вызвать сразу:

```
>>> (lambda x: x if x else None)([i for i in range(10)])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[HtmlParser(el) for el in content.select('...') or []]
```

`or` вернёт первое значение имеющее значение `True` либо последнее значение