# Как взять определённый элемент из списка без поднятия исключения?

Tags: python

Надо взять первый элемент из списка который возвращает xpath метод. Проблема в том что список может быть пустым и тогда поднимается исключение. Как можно его подавить или может у etree есть особый метод который возвращает либо объект либо None?

Comment: пустой список означает Faulse при проверке в if, можно воспользоваться этим

Comment: Надо чтобы в одну строку было

Comment: Вы задавали похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758647/Аналог-нуль-коалесцирующего-оператора-в-Питоне

Comment: Нет, тут вообще речь о другом. Там надо было в случае None вернуть пустой список, а тут надо взять первый элемент и в случае его отсутствия вернуть дефолтное значение. Это аналог get у словаря только по индексу

Comment: "Надо чтобы в одну строку было"? присвоение в одну строку?